# Angularjs model not binding to view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code on my view...

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#/dashboard" id="breadcrumb-dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/restaurants">Restaurants</a></li>
    <li class="active">{{ restaurant.name }}</li>
</ol>

...

<label for="restaurant-name">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="restaurant-name" class="form-control"
       ng-model="restaurant.name" placeholder="Name">
```

My Controller looks like this...

```
req = {
   method: "GET",
   url: "data/new_restaurant.json",
   headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
   }
};

$http(req).then(function(response) {
   $scope.restaurant = response.data;
}
```

The JSON data file looks like this.

```
{
   name: "Bob's Bellicose Burritos"
}
```

The problem I have is that the first restaurant.name in the breadcrumb works perfectly. However, the text input field doesn't reflect the current value of restaurant.name and doesn't bind so that it updates when you enter something in the text field. I am importing $scope, $routeParams and $http into the controller.

I'm completely stumped. When I debug, the console shows that the $scope.restaurant object has the correct information. Changing the text field doesn't make any changes on the $scope.restaurant object though.

Also, I have a lot more fields on the $scope.restaurant object but none of them are working. I didn't figure copy/pasting a crap-ton of code would be helpful. I'm happy to share a more complete code listing if required.

Thanks for any help you can give me. This has me pounding my head on the desk.

Comment: Is it in a different controller? Same controller different instance? Can you post more html?

Comment: Are both `<input>` and `<ol>...</ol>` part of same controller?

Comment: Are you sure breadcrumb and field are in the same scope?

Comment: They are all in the same controller.

`adminControllers.controller('RestaurantDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
... stuff goes here...
} ]);`

Comment: They are all in the same $scope.  I only have 1 $scope on the page.

Comment: please show the complete controller and view

Comment: Your HTML code is what everyone is interested in.

Comment: what is your console.log($scope.restaurant)? From where you got response.data?

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
<input type="text" id="restaurant-name" class="form-control"
   ng-model="name" placeholder="Name">

 $http(req).then(function(response) {
        $scope.restaurant = response.data;
        $scope.name=$scope.restaurant.name
  }
```